# FBLoginView : thrown an error after clicking the login button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, loginview

I have a stack trace here but have no idea what is wrong and there is not obvious output on the console screen.

```
> #0    0x01e1f09b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x00096ebf in -[FBLoginView informDelegate:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBLoginView.m:292
#2  0x00097104 in -[FBLoginView observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBLoginView.m:340
#3  0x01847ce7 in NSKeyValueNotifyObserver ()
#4  0x018613f4 in NSKeyValueDidChange ()
#5  0x01816630 in -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] ()
#6  0x018c335a in _NSSetIntValueAndNotify ()
#7  0x0007c9ef in -[FBSession transitionToState:andUpdateToken:andExpirationDate:shouldCache:loginType:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:767
#8  0x0007b792 in -[FBSession openWithBehavior:completionHandler:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:350
#9  0x0007f2a6 in +[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:allowLoginUI:allowSystemAccount:isRead:defaultAudience:completionHandler:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:1558
#10 0x0007bff1 in +[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:545
#11 0x000973f9 in -[FBLoginView buttonPressed:] at /Users/jacl/src/release/ios-sdk/src/FBLoginView.m:391
```

Does anyone see this error before? This happen when i click the login button in the FBLoginView

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably that the FBLoginView object is deallocated before the message is sent to it. Enable "Zombie Objects" in your scheme to get a clearer output.

Please paste your code where the FBLoginView is used if you want a more detailed answer.